# Is it possible to connect to spring boot embedded ActiveMQ instance from another application(started in separate process)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I've read several [examples](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/) about jms support in spring boot.

and usually sender, receiver and active-mq(actually it can be any other jms compatible message broker) locates within the same application.

I know that I can use stand alone active mq and [use propertie](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html)s:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://192.168.1.210:9876
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=secret
```

But I want to have 2 applications:

1- sender (connects to jms from receiver embedded and sends messages there)
2-receiver (up application and embedded activemq)

Is it posiible?

Comment: As I understand your question number 2-receiver contains an embedded ActiveMQ server. Is this correct?

Comment: @gil.fernandes - you are correct

Comment: In theory there should be no problem in doing what you propose. After all ActiveMQ is written in Java and can run embedded in another application and should be able to behave in the same manner as simply running standalone. You can do the same thing with an http server ...

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399072/spring-boot-configure-multiple-activemq-instances/43401330#43401330

Comment: not sure of I understood your question.
There are two applications, Sender and Reciever. Reciever has embedded activemq.  And sender application should connect to this embedded activemq from Reciever and send message. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @pvpkiran, your suggestion is correct

Comment: Not possible. If it were possible, then there is no meaning to embedded right. How can you connect to an embedded activemq from outside of application. If Sender and Reciever are in same application, then yes it is possible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add a `BrokerService` bean to your application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48504265Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48504265Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
        BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        return broker;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("foo", "AMessage");
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
```

and add this to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If I understand correct you have sender(runner), receiver(@JmsListener) and activeMq(broker()) within the single aplication

Comment: That is correct in this example but, because the broker is listening on the `tcp://` transport instead of the default `vm://`, other applications can connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your config to access local or remotely

```
@Bean
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector("tcp://0.0.0.0:61616");
    brokerService.setPersistent(false);
    return broker;
}
```