# How to start activemq in Unix at Application startup

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I would like to start ActiveMQ when my Unix server gets started.

I am using the following the config

Broker URI : tcp://localhost:61616

Above ActiveMQ server will get started when I run ActiveMQ start command from UNIX terminal but I want to start it when my server gets started so the user can directly go and access the application.

As of now, we have to manual start ActiveMQ from the directory

Application details: Java spring based web application
ActiveMQ version : 5.14.5

Server: Tomcat

DB: Internal Kahab DB

Everything is working fine but we cant tell every user to start ActiveMQ manually.

Please forgive me if I am missing any Architectural base things.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `BrokerService` bean to your application.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504265/is-it-posiible-to-connect-to-spring-boot-embedded-activemq-instance-from-another/48504606#48504606).