# How to send messages to multiple jms (active mq) brokers from the same application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I've up 2 applications(servers) with embedded active mq instances locally.

Now I need to create a client for this servers.

I've read the asnswer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401330/2674303

and try to repeat this:

I registered 2 connection factories:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ConnectionFactory bitFinexExchangeJmsConnectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory hitbtcExchangeJmsConnectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61617");
}
```

registered 2 jms templates:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public JmsTemplate bitfinexJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(bitFinexExchangeJmsConnectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("robotCommand_bitfinex");
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate hitBtcJmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(hitbtcExchangeJmsConnectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("robotCommand_hitbtc");
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

and wrote following main method in my spring boot application:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(RobotApplication.class, args);
JmsTemplate bitfinexJmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class, "bitfinexJmsTemplate");
bitfinexJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("robotCommand", "message to bitfinex");

JmsTemplate hitBtcJmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class, "hitBtcJmsTemplate");
hitBtcJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("robotCommand", "message to hitbtcc");
```

In client I see that only `message to bitfinex` was delivered.

I started to investigate issue and found out that `hitBtcJmsTemplate` uses `bitFinexExchangeJmsConnectionFactory`. I tried to change my main method code:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(RobotApplication.class, args);
JmsTemplate bitfinexJmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class, "bitfinexJmsTemplate");
bitfinexJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("robotCommand", "message to bitfinex");

JmsTemplate hitBtcJmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class, "hitBtcJmsTemplate");
hitBtcJmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory) context.getBean("hitbtcExchangeJmsConnectionFactory")); //  <---- additional line
hitBtcJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("robotCommand", "message to hitbtcc");
```

and both servers got the message.

Thus it is clear that my configuration is wrong. Please help to correct it.

Comment: Are those Brackets () after the Bean annotation where bitfinexJmsTemplate  is defined intentional?

Comment: @DaveH Actually I can remove it. I just tried to set name using the annotation but decided to remove it

Comment: @DaveH actually I tried to  remove it and test one time - no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use the wrong getBean method !!

```
<T> T getBean(java.lang.Class<T> requiredType,
              java.lang.Object... args)
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-

change to

```
JmsTemplate bitfinexJmsTemplate = context.getBean("bitfinexJmsTemplate", JmsTemplate.class);

JmsTemplate hitBtcJmsTemplate = context.getBean("hitBtcJmsTemplate", JmsTemplate.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `@Qualifier`. If you are getting a bean using `@Autowired`, then you can do like this

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("hitBtcJmsTemplate")
JmsTemplate hitBtcJmsTemplate;
```

If you want to get it from ApplicationContext, You have to use BeanFactory. because Beanfactory has a method to specify Qualifier. You can do like this

```
BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(applicationContext.getBeanFactory(), JmsTemplate.class, "hitBtcJmsTemplate");
```